# Magento 2 checkout payment page doesn't works because European server (ec.europa.eu) is down?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, soap, vat

I'm getting this error in the checkout page, when I click for the **payment step**:

> "Fatal Error: 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   \"http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl\"\n'
>   in '/path/to/project/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Vat.php' on
>   line 221"

The error is returned by an ajax call that tries to post `shipping-information`, as you can see in the following images.

Javascript console:
[image]

Network tab:
[image]

I think the error is due because the service that **validates the VAT number** (checkVatService?wsdl) is down in this moment.

Is there a way to avoid this and skip the vat number validation?

Comment: Did you receive this error a few hours ago as well? Or is it more consistent?

Comment: @LukeRodgers I'm getting this error since some hours. Never had before today.

Comment: I've had it too for the first time today. Perhaps the endpoint is experiencing errors. Try contacting them directly?

Comment: http://sorry.ec.europa.eu/ "Server is temporarily unavailable". Yep. I guess there may be functionality in magento to disable this check? It's an optional feature in magento 1

Comment: @LukeRodgers It think the service is working again now.

Comment: But it could be useful to disable such functionality, to avoid this in the future. Do you know how to do it? Could it be related with the feature for automatically assign a customer to a group if he/she have a vat number? Because on other websites I didn't had this error and the automatically assignment was disabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52316/discussion-between-luke-rodgers-and-andrea).